# error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile

Tags: ssl, curl

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/usr/share/ssl/certs/www.site.com.crt ");
```

The code given above is used for a payment section.  The following error is displayed:

%s: s77
error setting certificate verify locations: CAfile: /home/site/public_html/usr/share/ssl/certs/www.site.com.crt CApath: none

how can fix this can anyone help me please

Thanks

Comment: try remove getcwd() and check if file has exactly such location

Answer (score 4):

I experienced the same problem, and as far as I can see, it seems to have something to do with Curl being unable to write to that folder, which doesn't make sense because I am root on this machine (and can write files to my cert directory.)

One way to get around this is to force Curl not to established secure connections with a certificate:

```
echo insecure >> ~/.curlrc
```

Comment: Better to not use HTTPS to avoid giving a false sense of security.

Answer (score 0):

See if your environment is pointing to a non-existent file:

```
$ env | grep SSL
SSL_CERT_FILE=C:/ruby200/cacert.pem
```

Also you have a space at the end of your file inside the quotes.